# Wordpress PDF Upload HTTP Error

Tags: wordpress

Having an issue where when you try to upload a pdf file in wordpress, regardless of size - it gives an http error. Images upload fine. Upload limit is 2mb, but that shouldn't be an issue if the pdf is under 1mb. Wordpress has been updated and issue is still there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Resize in php.ini setting upload file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```